# Objective-C warning, Use of undeclared identifier 'new'

Tags: ios, byte, nsdata, zlib

I am getting this error

**Use of undeclared identifier 'new'**

on this line of code

```
Byte* decompressedBytes = new Byte[COMPRESSION_BLOCK];
```

This is my method that this line of code appears in.

```
//  Returns the decompressed version if the zlib compressed input data or nil if there was an error
+ (NSData*) dataByDecompressingData:(NSData*)data{
    Byte* bytes = (Byte*)[data bytes];
    NSInteger len = [data length];
    NSMutableData *decompressedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:COMPRESSION_BLOCK];
    Byte* decompressedBytes = new Byte[COMPRESSION_BLOCK];

    z_stream stream;
    int err;
    stream.zalloc = (alloc_func)0;
    stream.zfree = (free_func)0;
    stream.opaque = (voidpf)0;

    stream.next_in = bytes;
    err = inflateInit(&stream);
    CHECK_ERR(err, @"inflateInit");

    while (true) {
        stream.avail_in = len - stream.total_in;
        stream.next_out = decompressedBytes;
        stream.avail_out = COMPRESSION_BLOCK;
        err = inflate(&stream, Z_NO_FLUSH);
        [decompressedData appendBytes:decompressedBytes length:(stream.total_out-[decompressedData length])];
        if(err == Z_STREAM_END)
            break;
        CHECK_ERR(err, @"inflate");
    }

    err = inflateEnd(&stream);
    CHECK_ERR(err, @"inflateEnd");

    delete[] decompressedBytes;
    return decompressedData;
}
```

I am not sure why this is appearing like this. This code is from [ObjectiveZlib](https://github.com/JeremyOT/ObjectiveZlib) and have read through it several times and am not trying to use it in my own code to decompress a zlib NSData object but am having this stopping me from progressing.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did this method work,is the file getting converted to zip format

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code is Objective-C++. You're trying to compile it as Objective-C. Rename the file to end in `.mm` instead of `.m` and it should work.

Specifically, the `new` and `delete` operators are C++ operators. They don't exist in C. Objective-C is a superset of C, and Objective-C++ is a superset of C++. However since those appear to be the only C++-isms in this code, if you'd rather stick with Objective-C, you can fix it by replacing two lines:

1. Replace `new Byte[COMPRESSION_BLOCK]` with `(Byte*)malloc(sizeof(Byte) * COMPRESSION_BLOCK)`
2. Replace `delete[] decompressedBytes` with `free(decompressedBytes)`

Comment: ahHA! I thought that .mm was an error in the example files... Thanks very much.. so how could I call one of these methods from one of my .m files? since the methods being declared with a + which is for local use is it not?

Comment: Oh thank you very much going to go try your new suggestions now :)

Comment: @HurkNburkS: `+` doesn't mean local use. It means class method. So if you just leave this code alone in its `.mm` file, you can call it with `[NSData dataByDecompressingData:someData]`. Make sure you have the `#import "NSData+zlib.h"` as well.

Comment: oh okay yup I think I will try that as i would like to have this modular (out of my class) on its own :) okay going to go try that all now :) thanks very mcuh for your help.

Comment: Okay so tried adding the files to my project then refrenceing them with #import but then I am getting this error back when I call the method to decompress. ** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSData dataByDecompressingData:]: unrecognized selector sent to class**

Comment: @HurkNburkS: Did you make sure the `NSData+zlib.mm` file is actually included in your target? I'm also assuming here that you left this method in its original category, as found in ObjectiveZlib. If instead you copied it into your own class, then you'd need to call `[YourClass dataByDecompressingData:someData]` instead.

Comment: okay that fixed it :P i had messed with the original category :( silly me. Thanks a bunch for the help man! you have been a ledgend!

Answer (score 1):

`new` is a C++ construct, not Objective-C. In the above code it should probably read

```
Byte* decompressedBytes = (Byte*) malloc(COMPRESSION_BLOCK);
```

and equally the `delete[] ...` line should be replaced by

```
free(decompressedBytes);
```

A more Objective-C like solution would be to use `NSMutableData` for it:

```
Byte *decompressedBytes = (Byte*)
   [[NSMutableData dataWithLength: COMPRESSION_BLOCK] mutableBytes];
```

in which case you don't need to release it (or `[[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:...]` and release version of the above).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help.. this code works with no warning messages HOWEVER! it's throwing an error with the data i am feeding it.... it Logs **inflate error: -3** which is being thrown off **CHECK_ERR(err, @"inflate");** inside the if(err == Z_STREAM_END) if statment ? what do you think might be causing this problem? bad data?

Comment: actually dont worry found out the header of the packet I am receiving is interfering with the decompression because that part is not compressed :) fixing it now.. thanks for your reasponse